# How to get a char from ASCII number

Tags: c, char, int, ascii

Hello. Im reading file using FILE and reading that using fgetc to read that.

fgetc function returns me int value of my chars in ASCII.

Now i want to print that data in char values.

How to convert my ascii numbers to chars?

Comment: With `putchar(ch);` which also takes `int` value.

Comment: `fgetc()` is not guaranteed to return an ASCII value.  That is common but, strictly speaking, implementation-defined behaviour.   Different values will be returned on systems that work with non-ASCII character sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely don't need any conversion. If the native character set on your system is ASCII (which is the most common) then no conversion is needed. `'A' == 65` etc.

That means to print a character you just print it, with e.g. `putchar` or `printf` or any other function that allows you to print characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 48;
printf("%c", x);
```

it will print 0, also you can do this

```
int x = 48;
char xx = (char)x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify format as for a char, like so:

```
printf("%c", number);

printf("%c", 65); // A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
for (i=97; i <=200 ; i++)
{
    printf("%d  %c,\t",i,i);
};
return 0;}
```

This will give you the whole chart upto 200.